# Getting an incorrect AVG() value for column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, hiveql

I'm writing a sql query that would groupby a column and return it's min, max and average values. Here's what I'm doing:

```
CREATE TABLE Nums (
patient_id VARCHAR(20),
val DOUBLE
);
INSERT INTO Nums
VALUES ("A", 100), ("A", 175), ("B", 200), ("B", 100), ("B",20), ("B",2000), ("B",4000);

select AVG(event_count), MIN(event_count), MAX(event_count)
from Nums a
join (select patient_id, count(*) as event_count from Nums group by patient_id) b
on a.patient_id = b.patient_id;
```

I'm getting the output for the following query as

```
AVG(event_count)    MIN(event_count)    MAX(event_count)
4.1429                       2             5
```

I get correct values for min and max, however I expected the average value to be 3.5. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any pointers on what I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: What your expected `average_count` ?

Comment: It's odd that a float column would contain such values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For ease of understanding, I've gone ahead and created your tables visually here. **Nums a** looks like

```
+ ---------- + ---- +
| patient_id | val  |
+ ---------- + ---- +
| A          | 100  |
| A          | 175  |
| B          | 200  |
| B          | 100  |
| B          | 20   |
| B          | 2000 |
| B          | 4000 |
+ ---------- + ---- +
```

The table from your subselect which you alias with **b** looks like

```
+ ------------------------- +
| patient_id | event_count  |
+ ---------- + ------------ +
| A          | 2            |
| B          | 5            |
+ ---------- + ------------ +
```

If you inner joined them and selected all their columns, you would see

```
+ ---------- + ---- + ------------ +
| patient_id | val  | event_count  |
+ ---------- + ---- + ------------ +
| A          | 100  | 2            |
| A          | 175  | 2            |
| B          | 200  | 5            |
| B          | 100  | 5            |
| B          | 20   | 5            |
| B          | 2000 | 5            |
| B          | 4000 | 5            |
+ ---------- + ---- + ------------ +
```

When you average, you are doing 29/7 = 4.1429.

It seems to me like you just want to average the numbers 2 and 5, which is your subselect table, so I would do something like

```
select AVG(event_count), MIN(event_count), MAX(event_count)
    from (
        select patient_id, count(*) as event_count
            from Nums
            group by patient_id
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT AVG(event_count),MIN(event_count), MAX(event_count)
FROM(
  SELECT patient_id, count(*) as event_count 
  FROM Nums GROUP BY patient_id
)M
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select AVG(event_sum), MIN(event_count), MAX(event_count)
from Nums a
join (select patient_id, count(*) as event_count,sum(val) as event_sum from Nums group by patient_id) b
on a.patient_id = b.patient_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Please you can use this query i think you get your expected result

```
select AVG(DISTINCT event_count), MIN(event_count), MAX(event_count)
from Numstest a
join (select patient_id, count(*) as event_count from Numstest group by patient_id) b
on a.patient_id = b.patient_id;
```